# Getting the path without the filename in windows

Tags: tcl

How do I get the path without the filename in windows through Tcl?
I have the full path like this:

`c:\My_Designs\ipcore_script\test\src\IP_CORE\mux\sus.do`

I need only the path and want to strip off the filename to get this:

`c:\My_Designs\ipcore_script\test\src\IP_CORE\mux`

Answer (score 6):

It's `dirname`, from the [manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.0/TclCmd/file.htm#M10):

> **file dirname** *name*
>
> Returns a name comprised of all of the path components in name excluding the last element. If name is a relative file name and only contains one path element, then returns `.'' (or` :'' on the Macintosh). If name refers to a root directory, then the root directory is returned. For example,
>
> **file dirname c:/**
>
> returns **c:/**.
>
> Note that tilde substitution will only be performed if it is necessary to complete the command. For example,
>
> **file dirname ~/src/foo.c**
>
> returns **~/src**, whereas
>
> **file dirname ~**
>
> returns **/home** (or something similar).

Comment: Also you can use file nativename in case you want to do anything Windows specific with the filename eg pass it to an exec call.

Comment: +1: I'd prefer to link to [more recent docs](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm#M13) myself, but they're identical for this command.

Answer (score 1):

```
set path1 [info script]
# get the path and file name of currently opened file   
puts $path1                          
# shows the path                                             
set dir1 [file dirname $path1]  
# getting the directory from the fullpath                           
puts $dir1
```